# How to get items from list by Conditions in java?

Tags: python, java, list

How can I get items by conditions? for example:

```
public class Candy {
    int SugarCantains = 0;
    Candy(int sugarcontains){
        this.SugarCantains = sugarcontains;
    }
    static List<Candy> candies = new ArrayList<>();

    {
        for (int I = 0; I < 9; I++){
            candies.add(new Candy(I))
        }
    }
}
```

And how can I get candies that SugarContains is less that 5 in list candies?

```
candies.getByConditions((SugarContains < 5));
```

I know I can use for loop:

```
List<Candy> LowSugarCandies = new ArrayList<>();
for (Candy c: candies){
    if (c.SugarContains < 5){
        LowSugarCandies.add(c);
    }
}
```

but it's too slow, are there any faster way to do that?

And I have same problem in python, how can I do that in python?

Comment: @Chris not at all, I also have same problem at python

Comment: Sure it does: `List<Candy> lowSugarCandies = candies.stream().filter(c -> c.SugarContains < 5).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: Python would look similar. Something like: `low_sugar_candies = list(filter(lambda c: c.sugar_contains < 5, candies))` or using a list comprehension: `low_sugar_candies = [c for c in candies if c.sugar_contains < 5]`.

Comment: If you really want to be clever: `low_sugar_candies = list(filter((5).__ge__, candies))`